# Domain of sender address does not exist (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: python, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail using `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and running into error Domain of sender address does not exist (in reply to MAIL FROM     command),I tried with different usernames but issue still persists,any pointers on how to fix it?

```
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 22:28:32 -0800 (PST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: username@fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="28C8A2004E5238.1518503312/fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <20180213062832.A40612004E533E@fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--28C8A2004E5238.1518503312/fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is the mail system at host fullusernames-macbook-pro-2.local.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<username@company.com>: host nwk-aaemail-lapp01.company.com[17.151.62.66] said: 553
    5.1.8 Domain of sender address does not exist (in reply to MAIL FROM
    command)

--28C8A2004E5238.1518503312/fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 28C8A2004E5238
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; username@fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Arrival-Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 22:22:09 -0800 (PST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; username@company.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;username@company.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.8
Remote-MTA: dns; nwk-aaemail-lapp01.company.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 553 5.1.8 Domain of sender address does not exist

--28C8A2004E5238.1518503312/fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: Read the error message more carefully. *Domain of **sender address** does not exist*. The sender of the email isn't a valid domain. Not the receiver, the **sender** (you, presumably).

Comment: @KenWhite - the sender is `username@fullusernames-MacBook-Pro-2.local` in this case?right?not sure why its picking the local one for sender..I give something like "username@company.com" which is valid, any pointers why?